# Difference between "Would have to " and "Will have to"

Tags: will-would

In a mobile purchasing guide, it says that you can have a small-sized phone very cheaply. The next sentence is:

> But what if you want a bigger screen? In that case you (would have to/will
>   have to) spend more money.

I think its "will have to" because it is a fact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["will" vs "would" in hypothetical situations](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129037/will-vs-would-in-hypothetical-situations)

Comment: I still dont get it fully.What is the difference in both cases?

Comment: consider this sentense I found on net:"I am an extremely easy-going guy, and I think I **would** fit in with almost anyone".I am wondering if I can replace "would" with "will".I am really confused here!

Answer (score 1):

Literally, they both mean the same.
Logically, "**would**" is used when the person is not completely sure/ is doubtful while "**will**" is used when one is sure that the thing is going to happen.

Comment: Then in this sentense: "I am an extremely easy-going guy, and I think I would fit in with almost anyone" ,do you think  that  "i think" and "I would" are redundant because both means that you are not sure? Why not say " i think i will" or just " i would"?

Comment: It's just used this way to clear up the logical meaning. A person could think and still be sure of the fact.

Answer (score 0):

'Will have to" is used for making a promise to do something in future. It's used in First Conditional where the condition is possible to fulfill in future :

> If you want a bigger screen, you will have to spend more money.

But 'would have to' is used  to be more polite to make some hypothetical statement. It is used in 2nd conditional where it denotes an unreal possibility, i.e., a condition in theory possible to fulfil :

> If you wanted a bigger screen, you would have to spend more money.

What if you want a bigger screen?

> In that case, the above-mentioned both conditionals are possible. But in my opinion, the 2nd conditional sounds more polite.

Comment: I totally agree with Sandip.

Answer (score 0):

'Would have to’ is correct in the context of a buying guide. It indicates that the action (purchasing the phone) is conditional. You only need to spend the additional money if you decide to get the bigger screen.

‘Will’ indicates that the action is unconditional ... it must happen regardless.